# Shorter way to create datacontext object?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a very simple question and would be great if someone could save me some typing in the future.

I see myself typing this statement often:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
```

I remember seeing a shorter version of it somewhere but can seem to find it. I believe it has  the name of the datacontext only typed once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
```

To abbreviate it even further you could do something like this:

```
using (var db = DataClass.DB())
```

Where DataClass has a static method DB that returns a new instance of your data context.

Comment: agreed; nothing wrong with a factory method, unless someone is specifically wanting an IoC/DI approach; in the case of db-contexts / connections, a factory method is instantly more appealing than a `new BlahBlah(blahBlah)`...

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
```

Answer (score 2):

I still have to do this too, usually in a repository. The only difference as others answered is to use the `var db` implicit definition. This works because you are instantiating a class explicitly with the `new` keyword so the compiler still knows that the type will be `DataClasses1DataContext`